# Pandas: Get highest value from a column for each unique value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

How to get the highest value in one column for each unique value in another column and return the same dataframe structure back.
Here is a pandas dataframe example?

```
       reg.nr   counter      value     ID2  categ             date
1       37367       421     231385      93      A       20.01.2004
2       37368       428     235156      93      B       21.01.2004
3       37369       408     234251      93      C       22.01.2004
4       37372       403     196292      93      D       23.01.2004
5       55523       400     247141      139     E       24.01.2004
6       55575       415     215818      139     F       25.01.2004
7       55576       402     204404      139     A       26.01.2004
8       69940       402     62244       175     B       27.01.2004
9       69941       402     38274       175     C       28.01.2004
10      69942       404     55171       175     D       29.01.2004
11      69943       416     55495       175     E       30.01.2004
12      69944       407     90231       175     F       31.01.2004
13      69945       411     75382       175     A       01.02.2004
14      69948       405     119129      175     B       02.02.2004
```

Where i want to return the highest value of column "counter" based on the unique value of column "ID2". After the new pandas dataframe should look like this:

```
       reg.nr   counter      value     ID2  categ             date
1       37368       428     235156      93      B       21.01.2004
2       55575       415     215818      139     F       25.01.2004
3       69943       416     55495       175     E       30.01.2004
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way using `drop_duplicates`

```
In [332]: df.sort_values('counter', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(['ID2'])
Out[332]:
    reg.nr  counter   value  ID2 categ        date
2    37368      428  235156   93     B  21.01.2004
11   69943      416   55495  175     E  30.01.2004
6    55575      415  215818  139     F  25.01.2004
```

For desired output, you could sort on two columns, and reset the index

```
In [336]: (df.sort_values(['ID2', 'counter'], ascending=[True, False])
             .drop_duplicates(['ID2']).reset_index(drop=True)
          )
Out[336]:
   reg.nr  counter   value  ID2 categ        date
0   37368      428  235156   93     B  21.01.2004
1   55575      415  215818  139     F  25.01.2004
2   69943      416   55495  175     E  30.01.2004
```

Comment: Thank you John for the answer, i accepted your answer because the execution time is 100 times faster with your method than Ilya V. Schurov method with grouping

Comment: I'm not very sure. I feel IIya's method would work faster for larger data. You'd need to test it out on your usecases.

Comment: on my sample of 110000 rows, yours executed in 0.031253 seconds whereas Ilya's in 1.84827 seconds, ok 60 times faster; but still much better

Comment: Wow, interesting :)

Answer (score 5):

```
df.loc[df.groupby('ID2')['counter'].idxmax(), :].reset_index()

   index  reg.nr  counter   value  ID2 categ        date
0      2   37368      428  235156   93     B  21.01.2004
1      6   55575      415  215818  139     F  25.01.2004
2     11   69943      416   55495  175     E  30.01.2004
```

First, you are grouping your dataframe by column `ID2`. Then you get `counter` column and calculate an index of (first) maximal element of this column in each group. Then you use these indexes to filter your initial dataframe. Finally you resets indexes (if you need it).

Comment: Thank you Ilya V. Schurov for the answer :)